# Error in replacing string using regular expressions

Tags: regex, perl, shell, replace

I have multiple jsp files in which I want to do something like this in order to avoid XSS. Basically use JSTL to escape the "value".

```
//change following line to use c:out
<input  type="hidden" id="crudProperty1" name="crudProperty1" value="${crud.property1}"></input> 

<input  type="hidden" id="crudProperty1" name="crudProperty1"  value="<c:out value="${crud.property1}"/>"></input>
```

Here's the script that I tried to use from the terminal, to do these changes for one of the files in a folder.

```
find . -type f -name "*.jsp" | xargs perl -i -p -e 's|" value=("\${.*}"?)|" value="<c:out value=\1/>"|'
```

This is essentially looking for any .jsp files, then looping over the output abd replacing the above mentioned text in-place. I am not quite sure what is going wrong, but I do not see any changes to the file. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Using perl is overkill for this task, sed can do the job.

Comment: I tried your script and it is working for me (perl v5.20.2).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It was actually working fine but there was an issue with the space before value in the regex. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use perl and xargs, you can do this task only with sed:

```
find . -type f -name "*.jsp" -exec sed -i 's#\(value="\)\(\${[^}]*}\)"#\1<c:out \1\2/>"#g' {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks, This does it perfectly fine!